# How does one prevent default types from being used in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, standards, tsconfig

There are some types, like `Element`, `Buffer`, `Text`, etc, which seem to be present in any TypeScript file, by default. I would like to enforce rigor for imports, to avoid conflicts in case of type redefinition.

1. Is there a setting for `tsconfig.json` which allows to do that ? To enforce a "no-default-types" (other than primitive types) sort of rigor ?
2. From where would one import these default types, if one wishes to use the "standard library" ?

Comment: They're present in the TS file because they'd be present in the JS file, they're part of the https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That at least answers part of question 2. However, I'd like a tsc error (or at least, warning) if one of these types is used without being explicitly imported. If there's no way to do that, that would be terrible OO namespace design.

Comment: Again, *those things exist in JS*. You may well consider that poor design, but that's what TS compilation targets.

Comment: Of course, but since they can be overridden by a new import; there's got to be a way to check if that override happens or not. If not, I'll make an issue on the TypeScript github, honestly

Comment: Does there? That footgun exists *in the target language*; you can overwrite those globals and, if you're not careful, potentially break stuff.

Comment: Well, I break stuff anyways if I (or someone on my team) redefine one of these obscure default types and it's not indicated anywhere (neither by saying "new type 'X' overrides standard type 'X'", nor "namespace conflict", nor "type 'X' is undefined", nor "type 'X' is used unimported, but option 'no-default-types' was set"). So clearly, there's an issue

Comment: Sure, but TS is a superset of JS. Look to linting for help with that: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-redeclare.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230632/discussion-between-tristan-duquesne-and-jonrsharpe).